# Wake-on-lan under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wakeonlan

I would like to setup the wake-on-lan, the two PCs are connected through a switch.

Here is the configuration of the eth0, in the BIOS I couldn't find any information regarding the wake-on-lan.

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

After I shut down the PC, I used different tools to send out the magic package, but nothing happens. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your card is supported, now to configure wake-on-lan:

1. Install `ethtool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ethtool
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/rc.local` to add this line before the `exit 0` line:

   ```
   ethtool -s eth0 wol g
   ```
3. Find out the MAC address of your network card (replace `eth` if with your interface name, `eth0`, `eth1`, ..):

   ```
   ifconfig eth | grep "HWaddr" | awk '{print $5}'
   ```
4. Shutdown the machine. You should be able to wake it up using:

   ```
   wakeonlan your_mac
   ```

Comment: I tried this, and I'm receiving the following address. `Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 4c:02:89:00:xx:xx
send : Network is unreachable at /usr/bin/wakeonlan line 126.`. But I'm connected to the network through a switch, I also can ping the UPS network card. What can be the problem?

Comment: try this one: `wakeonlan -i 192.168.0.255 mac`. Where you might have to replace 192.168 to reflect your network.

Comment: Also make sure your network card really is in standby mode: there should be a green or yellow LED light.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: I can't test now, because the PC is not in the office

Comment: Note that step 2 is probably useless here - in the ethtool output, the `Wake-on` entry is already on `g`. I didn't have to execute this step.

Comment: Also, step 0, enable PCI wakeup in the BIOS of the motherboard. This is usually disabled by default.

Comment: According to Ubuntu Help Docs, they rec placing the line "up ethtool -s eth0 wol g" at the bottom of your /network/interface eth0 configuration line. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan , but like others mine was already on by default. I still added it tho! Don't think it will hurt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install ethtool by typing with root privilage:

```
apt-get install ethtool
```

Next step is to enable wake on lan in your system by typing:

```
ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

I describe such scenario and few optional next [step on my blog](http://lukasz-lademann.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-set-up-wol-wake-on-lan-on-thin.html)