# Wake-on-LAN works with Windows 8 but not with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, shutdown, wakeup, wakeonlan

I have a PC that has a Windows 8 partition and an Ubuntu 13.04 partition.  I am trying to get wake-on-lan to work.  Everything works fine on the Windows 8 partition: I can wake-on-lan from both the sleep state and the shutdown state. However, when I shutdown Ubuntu using:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

I cannot wake the PC through my LAN. Is this because the network interface is getting turned off? What command can I use or how can I reconfigure Ubuntu so that wake-on-lan still works?

Also, if I do not use the -h option in the shutdown command, the PC does not actually shutdown; it just freezes up on me.

Using ethtool, I found that it says:

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
...
Link detected: yes
```

My etc/network/interfaces says this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
      up ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

**EDIT:** I have found that if I shut down the PC by simply holding the power button, then wol works. If I shutdown using the command line or through the Ubunutu GUI, then it does not work. So I think the issue is not that it is not being setup properly, but that something is overriding it or shutting it off when I shut down properly. Are there are any scripts that get run at shutdown?

I have added

```
NETDOWN=no
```

to both etc/default/halt and etc/init.d/halt

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/210890/wake-on-lan-under-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @Mitch No, I really don't think so.  How does that question answer my question?

Comment: I didn't say that it answers your question, merely a chance for you to look at it.

Comment: @Mitch The ethtool mentioned in that question seems very useful.  See my edits for more info on my problem.

Comment: What have you done to configure the interface? Have you changed your /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: @jkurtisr32 Yes. The changes I made seemed to break my network connection.  See the edits above.

Comment: Dude, that's a Debian how-to. Use the Ubuntu one: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu+wake+on+lan

Comment: @jkurtisr32 Just tried that how-to. Didn't seem to fix things.

Answer (score 2):

Your commands are close, but try this in command line:

```
sudo ethtool -s <NIC> wol g
```

or add this to your /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    up ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

'g' enables wake via "Magic Packet"

Looks like if you are shutting down using the following command:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

then you will also need to edit your /etc/default/halt file. Add the following line:

```
NETDOWN=no
```

and see if that works. That should prevent the -h (halt) from shutting down the network interfaces.

Comment: See updates. I use g now. Still doesn't work if I shut down through CLI, but apparently works if hold down power button.

Comment: See edit. I am determined to solve this one, haha

Comment: It actually did not work. I added that to both /etc/default/halt and /etc/init.d/halt. Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: No problem, dude. Can you confirm that running the command `sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g` then shutting down does not help WOL work?

Comment: Yep. Confirmed. Only works when I hold down power button or when I shutdown from Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I got mine working (just done this this morning)

I created a file as root/sudo in /etc/init.d/ called wakeonlanconfig with the following in it

```
#! /bin/bash
ethtool -s eth0 wol g
exit
```

then I set the permissions on this file to

```
sudo chmod a+x wakeonlanconfig
```

then to make sure it executed on startup I did

```
sudo update-rc.d -f wakeonlanconfig defaults
```

and rebooted the machine, powered it down again and then from another machine on the network used the wakeonlan command to startup it up again

```
wakeonlan <mac address of machine to be woken up>
```

hey presto machine booted up, hope this helps

Comment: You should be able to make the WOL setting permanent by adding the setting to your /etc/network/interfaces file rather than creating a new init script. This method also works though