# WakeOn-LAN automated script

Tags: 18.04, scripts, wakeonlan

How would I go about having a desktop shortcut to run a script that sends a WakeOn-LAN packet with the same settings as this graphical online version? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/woli

Also, this is not directly Ubuntu related, but can anyone tell me why it only works using subnet mask 255.255.255.255 and not 255.255.255.0 as my router specifies?

I'm also Linux illiterate btw.

Comment: Perhaps this can be usefull: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210890/wake-on-lan-under-ubuntu-12-04/240694#240694

Comment: I, unfortunately, don't understand 90% of that article. When it says: "Change to the startup script directory and start editing a new file:" I go, what directory, how do I change it, how do I edit a file, what file? As I wrote, I'm Linux illiterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install [gWakeOnLAN](http://www.muflone.com/jekyll/gwakeonlan/english/) application:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gwakeonlan
```

Comment: So I already installed wakeonlan I think, how do I go about removing that, so I can install gwakeonlan instead?

Comment: They should not be in conflict, I think. But you can use `sudo apt-get remove wakeonlan` for removal.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I have now added my machine, how do I go about waking it up without having to launch terminal to launch the gwakeonlan gui, is there a way to make it a single click shortcut?

Comment: It should have its regular desktop launcher. You can place it on desktop.

Comment: Yes, but in something like windows you can make a shortcut that launches an application in a way that automates the thing you want to do, I guess that isn't a thing on Linux?

Comment: WoL is really a single magic packet, you can write a script for it while using `wakeonlan` package. Then attach this script to desktop or panel launcher. Or consult with `gwakeonlan --help` about possible scripting.